# Subviews overlap when scrolling UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a problem with the reusable cell.

When I scroll, new views (images, labels etc) are created and overlap on each other.

I've tried to remove all the cell subviews as soon as I create the reusable cell, but the result is that the table view is always empty.

Moreover, I cannot just set all the cell elements to `nil`, because several of them are dynamically created inside `cellForRowAtIndexpath`.

How can I solve this issue? I've been on it for quite a long time.